# Cakephp SQL Error 1054 Unknown Column In The Field List

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am trying to update multiple records in one field in my database. For some reason I keep getting SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column '520947b9' in 'field list'. 502947B9 is apart of my ID. Im not understanding why that value is being seen as a field list. Here is my code. That said, Im not sure Im updating these records correctly. If Im not please point it out to me. Thanks!!

```
public function findPolicyIds($coverageId = null) {
    $policyid = $this->Policy->find('all', array(
        'recursive' => -1,
        'conditions' => array('Policy.coverage_id' => $coverageId),
        'fields' => array('Policy.id')));

        foreach($policyid as $id) {
        $all[] = $id['Policy']['id'];

        foreach ($all as $key) {
        $this->Policy->Declination->updateAll(
              array('Declination.policy_id' => $key),
              array('Declination.coverage_id <=' => $coverageId)
            );
        }



    }

}
```

Here are my errors

Query: UPDATE `declinations` AS `Declination` LEFT JOIN `policies` AS `Policy` ON (`Declination`.`policy_id` = `Policy`.`id`) SET `Declination`.`policy_id` = 520947b9-0210-4067-94ea-70f8ae78509d  WHERE `Declination`.`coverage_id` <= '520947b9-1fa0-45db-992e-70f8ae78509d'

Query: UPDATE `declinations` AS `Declination` LEFT JOIN `policies` AS `Policy` ON (`Declination`.`policy_id` = `Policy`.`id`) SET `Declination`.`policy_id` = 520947b9-0694-4724-b353-70f8ae78509d  WHERE `Declination`.`coverage_id` <= '520947b9-1fa0-45db-992e-70f8ae78509d'

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of your query, `updateAll` is not recognizing `$key` as a string. Either cast it as such, or add the `'` characters yourself. Example:

```
$this->Policy->Declination->updateAll(
          array('Declination.policy_id' => "'".$key."'"),
          array('Declination.coverage_id <=' => $coverageId)
        );
```

That's the SQL error.

Now

> "That said, Im not sure Im updating these records correctly."

... Well, what do you want to do? Reading your code, You are getting an array of Policy's ids and updating all Declinations with a `coverage_id <= $coverageId`, which doesn't make much sense, since that foreach is updating the policy_id for that same condition, so in the end you will perceive the last change: last policy_id of the foreach on every Declination with coverage_id equal or less than `$coverage_id`.... Doesn't make much sense to me, even not knowing what you need to do.

Comment: $key is an indexed array. I was trying to loop through that array and save the id for each instance. Im going to go back and revist my code. That said, thanks Nunser!! You always hop in and give me some direction! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @SkillSet, no problem :).  `$key` is an indexed array, but you're not using the index anywhere, and the index is a numeric one not really related to anything at a simple glance, that's confusing. If you don't change the updating conditions, then that foreach will only overwrite on each loop. If you give us more background and what you want to do, maybe we can help you more.

Comment: I want to update all Declinations.Policy_Id's that have the same CoverageId that is being passed in.

Comment: update it with what? right now you are updating the same declinations over and over and the only result is that the declarations with coverage_id <= $coverageId will have the last policy_id in the loop. And if it is "the same coverageId", then remove the `<=` in the conditions array of the updateAll.

Comment: Ok, but look. Let's say you have 3 policies with that coverage id. And you have 1 declination with that coverage id also. Then you cannot have 3 policies ids in `Declination.policy_id`column when you update the declaration table. You have to choose one or change the relation between declarations and policies for `hasMany` o HABTM.

Comment: This what I've got....Coverage hasMany Policy....Policy belongsTo Coverage....Policy hasMany Declination...Declination belongsTo Policy. You have to have 3 Declinations per Policy. I want to save all Policy Id's ($Key) to the Declination.Policy_id field so that I can track which declinations belong to which policy. I need to save those Id's for the records that are equal to the CoverageId being passed in. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the SQL and assuming you are using an ORM, it appears to me that policy_id is defined as an numeric field in your Declination model when it really needs to be a string.  Coverage_id field is working correctly, so compare the two definitions.